# How to solve this distinct problem in Linq?

Tags: c#, database, linq

First, I'll describe my table structure a bit. There are two tables, FormField and Field.

A field can be linked to multiple formfields, but a formfield can only contain one field.

So I have this Linq Query:

```
var fields = from f in Data.Field.All()
                     join ff in formfields on f.Field_rid equals ff.Field_rid
                     select new
                     {
                         FormField = ff,
                         Field = f
                     };
```

Now, I am needing to put a distinct somewhere in there, but I can't figure out where. Basically, I don't want for the same Field to be returned to me more than once(so I never get a duplicate field). Where would I use the distinct function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distinct` doesn't seem to help you if you have multiple `formFields` per `field` and want to receive only distinct `fields`. But if you can think of some method to select only one `formField` from all field's formFields then it can be easily done:

```
// assumimg that for all fields we want to receive only formField with minimum Field_rid
var fields = Data.Field.All()
               .Select(f => new 
                    {
                        Field = f,
                        FormField = formFields
                                        .Where(ff => ff.Field_rid == f.Field_rid)
                                        .OrderBy(ff => ff.Field_rid)
                                        .FirstOrDefault(),
                    });
```

Comment: that is the solution I was looking for. And FirstOrDefault is fine because there should(in theory) never be more than one field tied to each formfield.

Comment: If so then you can strict it by replacing `FirstOrDefault()` with `Single()` to test whether your theory is still relevant.